# Is this pair of coupled sequences known, and what are their properties?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sequences-and-series

I was examining the following pair of 'coupled' sequences (I don't know the correct terminology):
$a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n+\frac{a_n}{b_n}$
$b_{n+1}=b_n\left(1+\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)$
Both sequences grow without bound if $b_0>1$ and if $a_0=b_0=1$ but if $a_0>1$ then sequence $b$ approaches a limit. For instance, if $a_0=2$ then $b_n$ approaches $4.0894$ and if $a_0=3$ then the $b$ limit is $2.2109$; neither of those are exact.
I found these sequences when examining two similar but simpler sequences:
$a_{n+1} = a_n + b_n$
$b_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$
I noticed that the b-sequence alternated between approaching a constant and growing somewhat exponentially. To try and capture this, I constructed the first pair of sequences, which give every other element of the second pair.
Is this pair of sequences already known of, and if so, what things are known about it? Does this system have a name? Where could I find literature about it?

Comment: It may be helpful to know how this recurrence arises.